# Count unrepeated customer within a group and make a tabulate

Tags: sas, pivot-table

I have the below data in SAS and I want to get the table with the number of customers buying a certain product in a certain time.

It does not count if a customer is repeated within the group.

```
Product customer interval
1       A         Morning
1       A         Morning
1       B         Afternoon
1       A         Evening
2       A         Afternoon
2       B         Morning
2       C         Afternoon
```

What I want to get is the below table

```
           Morning     Afternoon   Evening   All
Product               Customer number
1           1             1          1         2
2           1             2          0         3
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to remove duplicates to make this table.

This is easily done by using the nodupkey option in a proc sort:

```
proc sort data = have out = want nodupkey; 
by product customer interval; 
run;
```

Here's a format that will correctly order the interval categories by putting spaces in front of the categories you want first:

```
proc format; 
    value $interval 
        "Morning" = "  Morning" 
        "Afternoon" = " Afternoon" 
        "Evening" = "Evening"; 
run;
```

And here's the tabulate statement:

```
proc tabulate data = want order = formatted; 
class product interval; 
tables product, interval = " " all / row = float misstext = "0" printmiss; 
keylabel n = " "; 
format interval $interval.; 
run;
```

This returns the following table:

```
        Morning  Afternoon Evening  All 
Product     
  1        1         1       1       3
  2        1         2       0       3
```

If there are missing values this will be more complicated.